# Objective-C: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <NotFoundViewController: 0x8888a80>

Tags: objective-c, segue, mknetworkkit

I'm building a weather application. In a condition I have to perform segue and change the view controller.
I use MKNetworkKit. If API doesn't return a value, I trigger the segue. In this screen I also create and show an animation.
Here's my code:

```
- (void)proccessCompletedWithSuccess:(BOOL)success withResponse: (NSArray *)response;
{
    if(success){
       //do something
    }else{
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NotFound" sender:self];
    }
}
```

GetWeather.m file:

```
#import "GetWeather.h"

@implementation GetWeather

-(MKNetworkOperation*)
urlForApi:(NSString*) urlForApi
path:(NSString*) path
params:(NSMutableDictionary*)params
completionHandler:(ApiResponseBlockForWeather) completionBlock
errorHandler:(MKNKErrorBlock) errorBlock {

    MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:path
                                              params:params
                                          httpMethod:@"GET"];

    [op addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation)
     {
         NSArray* returningArray = [completedOperation responseJSON];

         NSString* description =[[[[returningArray valueForKey:@"query"]
                                   valueForKey:@"results"]
                                  valueForKey:@"channel"]
                                 valueForKey:@"description"];

         if ([description isEqualToString:@"Yahoo! Weather Error"]) {

             [self.delegate proccessCompletedWithSuccess:NO withResponse:nil];

         }else{
             [self.delegate proccessCompletedWithSuccess:YES withResponse:returningArray];
         }

         if([completedOperation isCachedResponse]) {
             //NSLog(@"weather response from cache");
         }
         else {
             //NSLog(@"weather response from server");
         }
         //   NSLog(@"%@",[completedOperation url]);
         completionBlock(returningArray);

     }errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *errorOp, NSError* error) {

         errorBlock(error);
         [self.delegate proccessCompletedWithSuccess:NO withResponse:nil];
     }];

    [self enqueueOperation:op];

    return op;
}

@end
```

And I got this error: `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <NotFoundViewController: 0x8888a80>.`

**Update:**
I tried performSelector with delay.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(performNotFound) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];

-(void)performNotFound{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NotFound" sender:self];
}
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: Is the performSegue being called multiple times? Can you try to log to see how many times it is being called?

Comment: It's been called two times

Comment: It's being called two times? Then you got your error...

Comment: I know this is the error but can't solve.. Can't find why trigger segue twice.

Comment: I had this problem with xibs. The async call to a web service was firing a UINavigationController push/pop.  While the web service was returning the data, the user could hit a back button, which would be a second transition.  This caused a unbalance begin and end.  The naviationController doens't queue transition, it just fires them as it gets them.

Comment: Yeah, my situation is very likely to your problem, So how can i solve this?

Comment: Try to create a singleton where you can track whether currently there is API call to get the weather. If it is YES, then avoid calling the API again when user go back and forth the view controller triggering the API call.

Comment: I tried this one, isn't it right? while(![self.getWeatherOperation isFinished]){}